# Running "ant gwtc" in GWT project gives error "Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later"

Tags: java, gwt, ant

I have a GWT project that I haven't built for a while, although I don't think much has changed.

When I run

```
ant gwtc
```

I get the output:

```
Buildfile: .../build.xml

libs:

javac:
    [javac] .../build.xml:31: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to .../war/WEB-INF/classes
    [javac] error: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
    [javac] error: Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.

BUILD FAILED
.../build.xml:31: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming back to this problem after a few months, within the generated build.xml file I found this block:

```
<target name="javac" depends="libs" description="Compile java source to bytecode">
  <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
  <javac srcdir="src" includes="**" encoding="utf-8"
      destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes"
      source="1.5" target="1.5" nowarn="true"
      debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
    <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
  </javac>
  <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
    <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.java"/>
  </copy>
</target>
```

And changed the source and target lines to 1.7.

```
<target name="javac" depends="libs" description="Compile java source to bytecode">
  <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
  <javac srcdir="src" includes="**" encoding="utf-8"
      destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes"
      source="1.7" target="1.7" nowarn="true"
      debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
    <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
  </javac>
  <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
    <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.java"/>
  </copy>
</target>
```

And everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be issue with the java version that you are using. From the logs that you posted, you seem to be using java version 5, which is not supported for your project and you need to use java version 7 or above versions.